# Multiplying each array inside another list with an element from another array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have created a list containing 10 arrays that consist of 20 random numbers between 0 and 1 each.

Now, I wish to multiply each array in the list with the numbers `0.05`, `0.1`, ..., to `1.0` so that none of the elements in each array is larger than the number it is multiplied with.

For example, all the `20` elements in the first array should lie between `0` and `0.05`, all the elements in the second array between `0` and `0.10` and so on.

I create a list of `10` random arrays and a range of numbers between `0` and `1` with:

```
range1 = np.arange(0.005, 0.105, 0.005)
noise1 = [abs(np.random.uniform(0,1,20)) for i in range(10)]
```

I then try to multiply the elements with:

```
noise2 = [noise1 * range1 for i in noise1]
```

But this doesn't work and just causes all the arrays in the list to have the same values.

I would really appreciate some help with how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried just normalizing the values to be within the range for 0 to 0.05, etc. ? x' = 0 + ((x - xmin)(0.05 - 0))/(xmax - xmin)

Comment: Why are you making a list of arrays instead of one big array? Also, you should use `linspace` instead of `arange` for floating-point values.

Comment: And did you notice you're not using `i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping I have clearly understood the question and hence providing this solution.

`noise2 = [noise1[i] * range1[i] for i in range(len(noise1))]`

Answer (score 0):

A more **pythonic** way would be using `zip`:

```
range1 = [1, 2, 3]
noise1 = [3, 4, 5]
noise2 = [i * j for i, j in zip(range1, noise1)]
# [3, 8, 15]
```